# Water on surge protector

Tags: water, safety, surge-suppression

Sorry if this is in the wrong place.

A couple of days ago I spilled a cup of water on the ground, and some of the water landed on a surge protector I quickly unplugged it and dried it off. I have kelp it in a warm room for a couple of days. 
Should I replace it, or is it safe to use it again?

Answer (score 2):

From your description it sounds like a small amount of tap water landed on the exterior of this surge protector and not much went into the receptacle holes. If this was tap water, then the surge protector will be safe to use. If this was water with vinegar or salt added, then it might be different.